# right align <time> in HTML

Tags: html, css

I am trying to right align a date (HTML `<time>` tag) with CSS. But it does not work. Why?
I can put `<time>` in a `<div>` and then apply CSS to `<div>`, but how to do it without the extra work?

[my code on glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/noon-powerful-whip)

```html
<h1 style="text-align: right;">i'm right-aligned</h1>
<time style="text-align: right;" datetime="2021-01-17">January 17<sup>th</sup> 2021(why not right-aligned?)</time>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like *span*, *strong*, *input*, and others, the *time tag* is also not a **block level element**.

In short, *time* is an **inline element**.
Block-level elements are those which occupy the full width of their parent e.g. *hr, div, p*.
Inline-elements occupy only the width of their content, so they can't be aligned to right without a block-level wrapper.

However, you could always use float with them.

```html
<time style="float: right;" datetime="2021-01-17">January 17<sup>th</sup> 2021</time>
```

Comment: Good appraoch by thinking that it is an inline-element. However I believe the `float` solution not as a good one. The issue is, that it is put out of the actual flow and can cause other issues. I would change it into a block level element by using `display: block` which prevent possible further issues.

Answer (score 0):

`<time>` tag has been dropped 2011 as it was repalced with the `<data>` tag. its supposed to be used within a text line. In fact it is supposed not to be used at all with the development of `<date>`.

the tag is just for readability and espacially screen-readers in mind. As such it should be placed within a text element. just wrap it inside a etxt element like a pargraph `<p>` and you can align the paragraph.

Alternativly you need to change the `<time>` tag into a block-level element and can then align them.

```css
p.time {
  text-align: right;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

time.time {
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<h1>Using Inline-Style:</h1>
<p style="text-align: right;"><time datetime="2021-01-17">January 17<sup>th</sup> 2021(why not right-aligned?)</time></p>

<br>

<h1>Using CSS:</h1>
<p class="time"><time datetime="2021-01-17">January 17<sup>th</sup> 2021(why not right-aligned?)</time></p>

<h1>Without wrapper:</h1>
<time class="time" datetime="2021-01-17">January 17<sup>th</sup> 2021(why not right-aligned?)</time>
```

Comment: thanks, how do you know it's dropped? as [MDN and w3schools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/time) suggest time tag is **living** standard.and why inline-level elements can't get aligned? why are they fixed? and why css float : right can do that but text-align : right can't?

Comment: w3school is not the most accurate and definetly not the best source for modern web development. The official HTML5 specifications are made by W3C and WHATWG (w3school is not related to W3C), they have dropped theem from the spec list. W3C as re-instated the tag nov 2011 but WHATWG did not. An article about it can be found here: https://www.brucelawson.co.uk/2011/goodbye-html5-time-hello-data/ and here: https://www.brucelawson.co.uk/2011/the-return-of-time/

Comment: is MDN unreliable too? because it says the same thing!

Comment: MDN is the mozilla documentation (actual developers network) Mozilla supports it because W3C has it listed.

Comment: This is incorrect. WHATWG do list it as a valid element. See [the <time> element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-time-element)

Comment: I stand corrected. I wonder what date they actually re-listed that.